# Bing maps Web Control V7 JS Exception

Tags: javascript, bing-maps, web-controls

In my application, I'm using Bing Maps Web Control V7 in witch I'm newbie.
Since nearly two weeks, I'm facing a **js** level exception

> Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

that I'm not able to find the cause.
Here's the stack trace :

```
1395e580.js?bu=rms+answers+MapsSDKRelease+AnonymousBegin*MapCore.fr*MapCoreBegin*LabelOptions*LocalStorageCache*Gimme*GimmeWrapper*evPromise*ExternalPromise*StaticPromise*LruCache*Point*Rectangle*NAARectangle*ResourceManager*Anchor*Size*Binding*EventBinding*Observable*ObservableObject*ObservableObjectChangedArgs*ObservableCollection*Debug*DelayLoadedObject*JSEvent*Dispatcher*WorkDispatcher*Iterator*ElementSizeHelper*GimmeExt*GimmeTransition*Helper*PerfState*ClientPerf*LoggingWrapper*LoggerConstants*Network*ThrottledEventInvoker*ObjectPool*StaticObjectPool*FixedSizeObjectPool*OrderedDictionary*PooledImage*Url*MapCoreMiddle*NavigationBarMode*NavigationBarOrientation*TransformCurve*CurveKey*Curve*Color*CurveVector4*CurveColor*Vector4*DiscreteRange*DiscreteRangeCollectionSpline*MapLayer*CopyrightProvider*CopyrightProviderService*CustomMapStyleManager*MapFrameManager*LayerFrameManager*GoalCounter*FrameEventAggregator*DataMonitor*MapFrameData*LayerFrameData*Clipper*CompositePrimitiveSet*DataLoader*Differ*FixedPrimitiveSet*PrimitiveSubset*Overlay*ImageryMapLayer*SimpleSceneContributor*VectorMapLayer*BasicMapAnimation*MapViewAnimator*BoundsAccumulator*CombinedLayerCollection*ConstrainViewArgs*LatLonCrs*LocationRect*Matrix2D*MapInstrumentationManager*PerfV2Logger*Map*MapHelper*MapMath*MapLocation*MapType*MapTypeChangeArgs*MapTypeCollection*MapTypeId*MapView*MapQuadrant*PrimitiveOverlayHelper*OverlayBehavior*GeometryGeneralizer*SimplePointPrimitive*SimpleLinePrimitive*SimpleAreaPrimitive*MoveableSimplePointPrimitive*TargetViewChangeArgs*VectorMath*ViewChangeArgs*ZoomLevel*ZoomAroundLocationAnimator*ZoomEventArgs*OverviewMapMode*MapAuthentication*PublicApi*InternalApi*AnonymousEnd:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at Function.n._clipExact (1395e580.js?bu=rms+answers+MapsSDKRelease+AnonymousBegin*MapCore.fr*MapCoreBegin*LabelOptions*LocalStorageCache*Gimme*GimmeWrapper*evPromise*ExternalPromise*StaticPromise*LruCache*Point*Rectangle*NAARectangle*ResourceManager*Anchor*Size*Binding*EventBinding*Observable*ObservableObject*ObservableObjectChangedArgs*ObservableCollection*Debug*DelayLoadedObject*JSEvent*Dispatcher*WorkDispatcher*Iterator*ElementSizeHelper*GimmeExt*GimmeTransition*Helper*PerfState*ClientPerf*LoggingWrapper*LoggerConstants*Network*ThrottledEventInvoker*ObjectPool*StaticObjectPool*FixedSizeObjectPool*OrderedDictionary*PooledImage*Url*MapCoreMiddle*NavigationBarMode*NavigationBarOrientation*TransformCurve*CurveKey*Curve*Color*CurveVector4*CurveColor*Vector4*DiscreteRange*DiscreteRangeCollectionSpline*MapLayer*CopyrightProvider*CopyrightProviderService*CustomMapStyleManager*MapFrameManager*LayerFrameManager*GoalCounter*FrameEventAggregator*DataMonitor*MapFrameData*LayerFrameData*Clipper*CompositePrimitiveSet*DataLoader*Differ*FixedPrimitiveSet*PrimitiveSubset*Overlay*ImageryMapLayer*SimpleSceneContributor*VectorMapLayer*BasicMapAnimation*MapViewAnimator*BoundsAccumulator*CombinedLayerCollection*ConstrainViewArgs*LatLonCrs*LocationRect*Matrix2D*MapInstrumentationManager*PerfV2Logger*Map*MapHelper*MapMath*MapLocation*MapType*MapTypeChangeArgs*MapTypeCollection*MapTypeId*MapView*MapQuadrant*PrimitiveOverlayHelper*OverlayBehavior*GeometryGeneralizer*SimplePointPrimitive*SimpleLinePrimitive*SimpleAreaPrimitive*MoveableSimplePointPrimitive*TargetViewChangeArgs*VectorMath*ViewChangeArgs*ZoomLevel*ZoomAroundLocationAnimator*ZoomEventArgs*OverviewMapMode*MapAuthentication*PublicApi*InternalApi*AnonymousEnd:1)
    at Function.n.clip (1395e580.js?bu=rms+answers+MapsSDKRelease+AnonymousBegin*MapCore.fr*MapCoreBegin*LabelOptions*LocalStorageCache*Gimme*GimmeWrapper*evPromise*ExternalPromise*StaticPromise*LruCache*Point*Rectangle*NAARectangle*ResourceManager*Anchor*Size*Binding*EventBinding*Observable*ObservableObject*ObservableObjectChangedArgs*ObservableCollection*Debug*DelayLoadedObject*JSEvent*Dispatcher*WorkDispatcher*Iterator*ElementSizeHelper*GimmeExt*GimmeTransition*Helper*PerfState*ClientPerf*LoggingWrapper*LoggerConstants*Network*ThrottledEventInvoker*ObjectPool*StaticObjectPool*FixedSizeObjectPool*OrderedDictionary*PooledImage*Url*MapCoreMiddle*NavigationBarMode*NavigationBarOrientation*TransformCurve*CurveKey*Curve*Color*CurveVector4*CurveColor*Vector4*DiscreteRange*DiscreteRangeCollectionSpline*MapLayer*CopyrightProvider*CopyrightProviderService*CustomMapStyleManager*MapFrameManager*LayerFrameManager*GoalCounter*FrameEventAggregator*DataMonitor*MapFrameData*LayerFrameData*Clipper*CompositePrimitiveSet*DataLoader*Differ*FixedPrimitiveSet*PrimitiveSubset*Overlay*ImageryMapLayer*SimpleSceneContributor*VectorMapLayer*BasicMapAnimation*MapViewAnimator*BoundsAccumulator*CombinedLayerCollection*ConstrainViewArgs*LatLonCrs*LocationRect*Matrix2D*MapInstrumentationManager*PerfV2Logger*Map*MapHelper*MapMath*MapLocation*MapType*MapTypeChangeArgs*MapTypeCollection*MapTypeId*MapView*MapQuadrant*PrimitiveOverlayHelper*OverlayBehavior*GeometryGeneralizer*SimplePointPrimitive*SimpleLinePrimitive*SimpleAreaPrimitive*MoveableSimplePointPrimitive*TargetViewChangeArgs*VectorMath*ViewChangeArgs*ZoomLevel*ZoomAroundLocationAnimator*ZoomEventArgs*OverviewMapMode*MapAuthentication*PublicApi*InternalApi*AnonymousEnd:1)
    at n.getPrimitives (1395e580.js?bu=rms+answers+MapsSDKRelease+AnonymousBegin*MapCore.fr*MapCoreBegin*LabelOptions*LocalStorageCache*Gimme*GimmeWrapper*evPromise*ExternalPromise*StaticPromise*LruCache*Point*Rectangle*NAARectangle*ResourceManager*Anchor*Size*Binding*EventBinding*Observable*ObservableObject*ObservableObjectChangedArgs*ObservableCollection*Debug*DelayLoadedObject*JSEvent*Dispatcher*WorkDispatcher*Iterator*ElementSizeHelper*GimmeExt*GimmeTransition*Helper*PerfState*ClientPerf*LoggingWrapper*LoggerConstants*Network*ThrottledEventInvoker*ObjectPool*StaticObjectPool*FixedSizeObjectPool*OrderedDictionary*PooledImage*Url*MapCoreMiddle*NavigationBarMode*NavigationBarOrientation*TransformCurve*CurveKey*Curve*Color*CurveVector4*CurveColor*Vector4*DiscreteRange*DiscreteRangeCollectionSpline*MapLayer*CopyrightProvider*CopyrightProviderService*CustomMapStyleManager*MapFrameManager*LayerFrameManager*GoalCounter*FrameEventAggregator*DataMonitor*MapFrameData*LayerFrameData*Clipper*CompositePrimitiveSet*DataLoader*Differ*FixedPrimitiveSet*PrimitiveSubset*Overlay*ImageryMapLayer*SimpleSceneContributor*VectorMapLayer*BasicMapAnimation*MapViewAnimator*BoundsAccumulator*CombinedLayerCollection*ConstrainViewArgs*LatLonCrs*LocationRect*Matrix2D*MapInstrumentationManager*PerfV2Logger*Map*MapHelper*MapMath*MapLocation*MapType*MapTypeChangeArgs*MapTypeCollection*MapTypeId*MapView*MapQuadrant*PrimitiveOverlayHelper*OverlayBehavior*GeometryGeneralizer*SimplePointPrimitive*SimpleLinePrimitive*SimpleAreaPrimitive*MoveableSimplePointPrimitive*TargetViewChangeArgs*VectorMath*ViewChangeArgs*ZoomLevel*ZoomAroundLocationAnimator*ZoomEventArgs*OverviewMapMode*MapAuthentication*PublicApi*InternalApi*AnonymousEnd:1)
    at n.getPrimitives (1395e580.js?bu=rms+answers+MapsSDKRelease+AnonymousBegin*MapCore.fr*MapCoreBegin*LabelOptions*LocalStorageCache*Gimme*GimmeWrapper*evPromise*ExternalPromise*StaticPromise*LruCache*Point*Rectangle*NAARectangle*ResourceManager*Anchor*Size*Binding*EventBinding*Observable*ObservableObject*ObservableObjectChangedArgs*ObservableCollection*Debug*DelayLoadedObject*JSEvent*Dispatcher*WorkDispatcher*Iterator*ElementSizeHelper*GimmeExt*GimmeTransition*Helper*PerfState*ClientPerf*LoggingWrapper*LoggerConstants*Network*ThrottledEventInvoker*ObjectPool*StaticObjectPool*FixedSizeObjectPool*OrderedDictionary*PooledImage*Url*MapCoreMiddle*NavigationBarMode*NavigationBarOrientation*TransformCurve*CurveKey*Curve*Color*CurveVector4*CurveColor*Vector4*DiscreteRange*DiscreteRangeCollectionSpline*MapLayer*CopyrightProvider*CopyrightProviderService*CustomMapStyleManager*MapFrameManager*LayerFrameManager*GoalCounter*FrameEventAggregator*DataMonitor*MapFrameData*LayerFrameData*Clipper*CompositePrimitiveSet*DataLoader*Differ*FixedPrimitiveSet*PrimitiveSubset*Overlay*ImageryMapLayer*SimpleSceneContributor*VectorMapLayer*BasicMapAnimation*MapViewAnimator*BoundsAccumulator*CombinedLayerCollection*ConstrainViewArgs*LatLonCrs*LocationRect*Matrix2D*MapInstrumentationManager*PerfV2Logger*Map*MapHelper*MapMath*MapLocation*MapType*MapTypeChangeArgs*MapTypeCollection*MapTypeId*MapView*MapQuadrant*PrimitiveOverlayHelper*OverlayBehavior*GeometryGeneralizer*SimplePointPrimitive*SimpleLinePrimitive*SimpleAreaPrimitive*MoveableSimplePointPrimitive*TargetViewChangeArgs*VectorMath*ViewChangeArgs*ZoomLevel*ZoomAroundLocationAnimator*ZoomEventArgs*OverviewMapMode*MapAuthentication*PublicApi*InternalApi*AnonymousEnd:1)
    at i._showLabelsForFrame (6fccc41e.js?bu=rms+answers+MapsSDKRelease+AnonymousBegin*LabelsPluginStart*LabelKey*LabelRegionBounds*Label*IconLabel*RelativePlacement*PointLabel*LineLabel*AreaLabel*ShieldLabel*CollisionIndex*CollisionManager*LabelerWorker*Labeler*LabelController*LabelCollider*LabelRenderer*CanvasLabelRenderer*VectorLabels*LabelsPluginEnd*AnonymousEnd:1)
    at Array.<anonymous> (6fccc41e.js?bu=rms+answers+MapsSDKRelease+AnonymousBegin*LabelsPluginStart*LabelKey*LabelRegionBounds*Label*IconLabel*RelativePlacement*PointLabel*LineLabel*AreaLabel*ShieldLabel*CollisionIndex*CollisionManager*LabelerWorker*Labeler*LabelController*LabelCollider*LabelRenderer*CanvasLabelRenderer*VectorLabels*LabelsPluginEnd*AnonymousEnd:1)
    at n.invoke (1395e580.js?bu=rms+answers+MapsSDKRelease+AnonymousBegin*MapCore.fr*MapCoreBegin*LabelOptions*LocalStorageCache*Gimme*GimmeWrapper*evPromise*ExternalPromise*StaticPromise*LruCache*Point*Rectangle*NAARectangle*ResourceManager*Anchor*Size*Binding*EventBinding*Observable*ObservableObject*ObservableObjectChangedArgs*ObservableCollection*Debug*DelayLoadedObject*JSEvent*Dispatcher*WorkDispatcher*Iterator*ElementSizeHelper*GimmeExt*GimmeTransition*Helper*PerfState*ClientPerf*LoggingWrapper*LoggerConstants*Network*ThrottledEventInvoker*ObjectPool*StaticObjectPool*FixedSizeObjectPool*OrderedDictionary*PooledImage*Url*MapCoreMiddle*NavigationBarMode*NavigationBarOrientation*TransformCurve*CurveKey*Curve*Color*CurveVector4*CurveColor*Vector4*DiscreteRange*DiscreteRangeCollectionSpline*MapLayer*CopyrightProvider*CopyrightProviderService*CustomMapStyleManager*MapFrameManager*LayerFrameManager*GoalCounter*FrameEventAggregator*DataMonitor*MapFrameData*LayerFrameData*Clipper*CompositePrimitiveSet*DataLoader*Differ*FixedPrimitiveSet*PrimitiveSubset*Overlay*ImageryMapLayer*SimpleSceneContributor*VectorMapLayer*BasicMapAnimation*MapViewAnimator*BoundsAccumulator*CombinedLayerCollection*ConstrainViewArgs*LatLonCrs*LocationRect*Matrix2D*MapInstrumentationManager*PerfV2Logger*Map*MapHelper*MapMath*MapLocation*MapType*MapTypeChangeArgs*MapTypeCollection*MapTypeId*MapView*MapQuadrant*PrimitiveOverlayHelper*OverlayBehavior*GeometryGeneralizer*SimplePointPrimitive*SimpleLinePrimitive*SimpleAreaPrimitive*MoveableSimplePointPrimitive*TargetViewChangeArgs*VectorMath*ViewChangeArgs*ZoomLevel*ZoomAroundLocationAnimator*ZoomEventArgs*OverviewMapMode*MapAuthentication*PublicApi*InternalApi*AnonymousEnd:1)
    at n._onLayerPrimitivesRendered (1395e580.js?bu=rms+answers+MapsSDKRelease+AnonymousBegin*MapCore.fr*MapCoreBegin*LabelOptions*LocalStorageCache*Gimme*GimmeWrapper*evPromise*ExternalPromise*StaticPromise*LruCache*Point*Rectangle*NAARectangle*ResourceManager*Anchor*Size*Binding*EventBinding*Observable*ObservableObject*ObservableObjectChangedArgs*ObservableCollection*Debug*DelayLoadedObject*JSEvent*Dispatcher*WorkDispatcher*Iterator*ElementSizeHelper*GimmeExt*GimmeTransition*Helper*PerfState*ClientPerf*LoggingWrapper*LoggerConstants*Network*ThrottledEventInvoker*ObjectPool*StaticObjectPool*FixedSizeObjectPool*OrderedDictionary*PooledImage*Url*MapCoreMiddle*NavigationBarMode*NavigationBarOrientation*TransformCurve*CurveKey*Curve*Color*CurveVector4*CurveColor*Vector4*DiscreteRange*DiscreteRangeCollectionSpline*MapLayer*CopyrightProvider*CopyrightProviderService*CustomMapStyleManager*MapFrameManager*LayerFrameManager*GoalCounter*FrameEventAggregator*DataMonitor*MapFrameData*LayerFrameData*Clipper*CompositePrimitiveSet*DataLoader*Differ*FixedPrimitiveSet*PrimitiveSubset*Overlay*ImageryMapLayer*SimpleSceneContributor*VectorMapLayer*BasicMapAnimation*MapViewAnimator*BoundsAccumulator*CombinedLayerCollection*ConstrainViewArgs*LatLonCrs*LocationRect*Matrix2D*MapInstrumentationManager*PerfV2Logger*Map*MapHelper*MapMath*MapLocation*MapType*MapTypeChangeArgs*MapTypeCollection*MapTypeId*MapView*MapQuadrant*PrimitiveOverlayHelper*OverlayBehavior*GeometryGeneralizer*SimplePointPrimitive*SimpleLinePrimitive*SimpleAreaPrimitive*MoveableSimplePointPrimitive*TargetViewChangeArgs*VectorMath*ViewChangeArgs*ZoomLevel*ZoomAroundLocationAnimator*ZoomEventArgs*OverviewMapMode*MapAuthentication*PublicApi*InternalApi*AnonymousEnd:1)
    at Array.<anonymous> (1395e580.js?bu=rms+answers+MapsSDKRelease+AnonymousBegin*MapCore.fr*MapCoreBegin*LabelOptions*LocalStorageCache*Gimme*GimmeWrapper*evPromise*ExternalPromise*StaticPromise*LruCache*Point*Rectangle*NAARectangle*ResourceManager*Anchor*Size*Binding*EventBinding*Observable*ObservableObject*ObservableObjectChangedArgs*ObservableCollection*Debug*DelayLoadedObject*JSEvent*Dispatcher*WorkDispatcher*Iterator*ElementSizeHelper*GimmeExt*GimmeTransition*Helper*PerfState*ClientPerf*LoggingWrapper*LoggerConstants*Network*ThrottledEventInvoker*ObjectPool*StaticObjectPool*FixedSizeObjectPool*OrderedDictionary*PooledImage*Url*MapCoreMiddle*NavigationBarMode*NavigationBarOrientation*TransformCurve*CurveKey*Curve*Color*CurveVector4*CurveColor*Vector4*DiscreteRange*DiscreteRangeCollectionSpline*MapLayer*CopyrightProvider*CopyrightProviderService*CustomMapStyleManager*MapFrameManager*LayerFrameManager*GoalCounter*FrameEventAggregator*DataMonitor*MapFrameData*LayerFrameData*Clipper*CompositePrimitiveSet*DataLoader*Differ*FixedPrimitiveSet*PrimitiveSubset*Overlay*ImageryMapLayer*SimpleSceneContributor*VectorMapLayer*BasicMapAnimation*MapViewAnimator*BoundsAccumulator*CombinedLayerCollection*ConstrainViewArgs*LatLonCrs*LocationRect*Matrix2D*MapInstrumentationManager*PerfV2Logger*Map*MapHelper*MapMath*MapLocation*MapType*MapTypeChangeArgs*MapTypeCollection*MapTypeId*MapView*MapQuadrant*PrimitiveOverlayHelper*OverlayBehavior*GeometryGeneralizer*SimplePointPrimitive*SimpleLinePrimitive*SimpleAreaPrimitive*MoveableSimplePointPrimitive*TargetViewChangeArgs*VectorMath*ViewChangeArgs*ZoomLevel*ZoomAroundLocationAnimator*ZoomEventArgs*OverviewMapMode*MapAuthentication*PublicApi*InternalApi*AnonymousEnd:1)
    at n.invoke (1395e580.js?bu=rms+answers+MapsSDKRelease+AnonymousBegin*MapCore.fr*MapCoreBegin*LabelOptions*LocalStorageCache*Gimme*GimmeWrapper*evPromise*ExternalPromise*StaticPromise*LruCache*Point*Rectangle*NAARectangle*ResourceManager*Anchor*Size*Binding*EventBinding*Observable*ObservableObject*ObservableObjectChangedArgs*ObservableCollection*Debug*DelayLoadedObject*JSEvent*Dispatcher*WorkDispatcher*Iterator*ElementSizeHelper*GimmeExt*GimmeTransition*Helper*PerfState*ClientPerf*LoggingWrapper*LoggerConstants*Network*ThrottledEventInvoker*ObjectPool*StaticObjectPool*FixedSizeObjectPool*OrderedDictionary*PooledImage*Url*MapCoreMiddle*NavigationBarMode*NavigationBarOrientation*TransformCurve*CurveKey*Curve*Color*CurveVector4*CurveColor*Vector4*DiscreteRange*DiscreteRangeCollectionSpline*MapLayer*CopyrightProvider*CopyrightProviderService*CustomMapStyleManager*MapFrameManager*LayerFrameManager*GoalCounter*FrameEventAggregator*DataMonitor*MapFrameData*LayerFrameData*Clipper*CompositePrimitiveSet*DataLoader*Differ*FixedPrimitiveSet*PrimitiveSubset*Overlay*ImageryMapLayer*SimpleSceneContributor*VectorMapLayer*BasicMapAnimation*MapViewAnimator*BoundsAccumulator*CombinedLayerCollection*ConstrainViewArgs*LatLonCrs*LocationRect*Matrix2D*MapInstrumentationManager*PerfV2Logger*Map*MapHelper*MapMath*MapLocation*MapType*MapTypeChangeArgs*MapTypeCollection*MapTypeId*MapView*MapQuadrant*PrimitiveOverlayHelper*OverlayBehavior*GeometryGeneralizer*SimplePointPrimitive*SimpleLinePrimitive*SimpleAreaPrimitive*MoveableSimplePointPrimitive*TargetViewChangeArgs*VectorMath*ViewChangeArgs*ZoomLevel*ZoomAroundLocationAnimator*ZoomEventArgs*OverviewMapMode*MapAuthentication*PublicApi*InternalApi*AnonymousEnd:1)
```

Does anyone have an idea ?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The Bing maps V7 SDK has been deprecated for a while now and is no longer available (deprecation was announced more than a year ago). An automatic redirect to V8 was put in place to help sites that had not yet migrated, but it's not 100% compatible.
You probably need to update your site to use the V8 map control - see this guide:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34563.bing-maps-v7-to-v8-migration-guide.aspx

Comment: That was the problem, i solved it by migrating WebControl to V8